# Time series modeling of choppy data

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to model 10 years of monthly time series data that is very choppy, and overall it has an upward trend. At first glance it looks like a strong seasonal series, however the test results indicate that it is definitely not seasonal. This is a pricing variable that I'm trying to model as a function of macroeconomic environment, such as interest rates and yield curves. I've tried linear OLS regression (proc reg), but I don't get a very good model with that. I've also tried autoregressive error models (proc autoreg), but it captures 7 lags of the error term as significant factors. I don't really want to include that many lag of the error term in the model. In addition, most of the macroeconomic variables become insignificant when I include all these error lags in the model.

Any suggestions on modeling method/technique that could help me model this choppy data is really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you post your data and we will find out what is going on .

Answer (score 1):

Sara,

Did you want to post your data to dropbox.com?

Have you plotted the normalized the Y and X's and done a scatterplot to see if there is a strong correlation between X and Y? See page 215 of the 2013 "Principles of Business Forecasting" by Keith Ord and Robert Fildes.

Have you looked at prewhitening your X's so that you can get a good crosscorrelation function so that you can decide which lead/lags to use?

Have you looked for outliers?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I provided a general framework from which to proceed.